# Use Stoke's Theorem to evaluate the line integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Use Stoke's Theorem to evaluate the line integral

$$\oint_C (y + 2z) dx + (x + 2z) dy + (x + 2y) dz$$

where $C$ is the curve formed by intersection of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and plane $x+2y+2z=0$.

I have done it this way...
z=-x/2-y
So n=(-gx(x,y),-gy(x,y),1)
   n=(1/2,1,1)
CurlF=(0,1,0)
so  CurlF.n=1
For evaluating surface integral I have used polar coordinates and answer turned out to be pi which is not correct answer.
I want to know what is wrong in my steps.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there a particular part of this giving you trouble?

Comment: yes ..I am unable to parametrize it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be sure to use a *unit* normal. Since $\text{curl }F\cdot n$ is constant, you'll just get a constant times the area of the disk. No parametrization or explicit integration needed.

By the way, it's easier to get the normal directly from the linear equation $a\cdot x=0$: We get $a=(1,2,2)$, and so $n=(1,2,2)/3$.

Comment: (Just a matter of time before you answered!)

Comment: Is my method wrong...because I watched a video on youtube where I learnt this method.

Comment: Your method is fine, but you need to be careful, as I said, to make sure your normal has length $1$ — and is pointing in the correct direction.